# MaterilizeCss Select not working after initializing

Tags: jquery, html, select, materialize

I am currently working with materializeCSS and I have a problem with `<select>`, after use:

```
 $("#formAddPoi").find('select').material_select()
```

this is my html generated code :

```
<div class="input-field col s12" id="selectCategorie">
  <div class="select-wrapper open">
    <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-96063ca2-82e2-19ca-74ce-8b9cc52a5a74" value="Selectionnez une catégorie" aria-expanded="true"><ul id="select-options-96063ca2-82e2-19ca-74ce-8b9cc52a5a74" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown "><li class=""><span>Selectionnez une catégorie</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/27.png" class="left circle"><span>Travail</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/127.png" class="left circle"><span>POI</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/195.png" class="left circle"><span>Dépôt</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/119.png" class="left circle"><span>Hôpital</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/106.png" class="left circle"><span>Garage</span></li><li class=""><img src="/Images/badge/02.png" class="left circle"><span>Station essence</span></li></ul><select class="initialized" name="poi.CategorieId">
      <option value="0">Selectionnez une catégorie</option>
      <option value="1" data-icon="/Images/badge/27.png" class="left circle">Travail</option>
      <option value="2" data-icon="/Images/badge/127.png" class="left circle">POI</option>
      <option value="3" data-icon="/Images/badge/195.png" class="left circle">Dépôt</option>
      <option value="4" data-icon="/Images/badge/119.png" class="left circle">Hôpital</option>
      <option value="9" data-icon="/Images/badge/106.png" class="left circle">Garage</option>
      <option value="10" data-icon="/Images/badge/02.png" class="left circle">Station essence</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>Catégorie</label>
</div>
```

But when I click on the select nothing appends.